# Getting json decode error even when receiving a json response (requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

**main.py**

```
req = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1', 
headers={'content-type':'application/json'})

print(req.json()) # json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

No idea why this is happening, I am adding the '?__a=1' query at the end so that I can get a response in json but it's not working, any help i appreciated!

Comment: Did you try printing the request status code and its contents as text? I have no trouble with your code

Comment: My guess is that you've tried this too many times and you're now getting HTTP 403. Check the status and see its value. If it's not 200 then there's no point in calling *json()*